# Проблема с core.editor

Tags: windows, git

У меня две проблемы:

- Не могу правильно прописать адрес для `core.editor` в терминале;
- Использование **vim** приводит к непонятной ошибке;

Так получилось что я первый раз пользуюсь терминалом и первый раз вижу **vim**. После первого `$ git commit` ошибки не было, открылся **vim** но я растерялся и в попытках закрыть редактор мог сделать что-то плохое, но что именно даже не представляю.

Да, `$ git commit -m "text"` работает. Но без `-m` работать тоже должно. На сколько я знаю в редактор должен отправлятся результат `$ git diff` и я хочу выяснить что натворил.

Переменная `$EDITOR` вроде бы пустая (результат пустая строка).
**Git** переустанавливал, комп перезапускал.

Сам по себе `$ vim` работает.

---

```
$ git config --global core.editor "'C:/Program Files/Git/usr/bin/vim'"
$ git commit
```

В файле `.gitconfig` адрес выглядит так: `editor = 'C:/Program Files/Git/usr/bin/vim'`

> E325: ВНИМАНИЕ
>   Aborting commit due to  empty commit message.

После этого сообщения я ничего не могу сделать в терминале.

---

```
$ git config --global core.editor vim
$ git commit
```

В файле `.gitconfig` адрес выглядит так: `editor = vim`

> E325: ВНИМАНИЕ
>   Error:  There was a problem  with the  editor 'vim'. Please supply the message using either -m or -F option.

После этого сообщения я ничего не могу сделать в терминале.

---

```
$ git config --global core.editor /usr/bin/vim
$ git commit
```

В файле `.gitconfig` адрес выглядит так: `editor = C:/Program Files/Git/usr/bin/vim`

> C:/Program Files/Git/usr/bin/vim: C:/Program: No such file or directory
>   error: There was a problem with the editor 'C:/Program Files/Git/usr/bin/vim'.
>   Please supply the message using either -m or -F option.

---

```
$ git config --global core.editor "C:/Program Files/Git/usr/bin/vim.exe"
$ git commit
```

В файле `.gitconfig` адрес выглядит так: `editor = C:/Program Files/Git/usr/bin/vim.exe`

> C:/Program Files/Git/usr/bin/vim.exe: C:/Program: No such file or directory
>   error: There was a problem with the editor 'C:/Program Files/Git/usr/bin/vim.exe'.
>   Please supply the message using either -m or -F option.

---

`$ vim --version`

```
VIM - Vi IMproved 8.0 (2016 Sep 12, compiled Jun  1 2017 21:25:47)
Заплатки: 1-606
Скомпилирован  <alexpux@gmail.com>
Огромная версия без графического интерфейса.
Включённые (+) и отключённые (-) особенности:
+acl             +file_in_path    +mouse_sgr       +tag_old_static
+arabic          +find_in_path    -mouse_sysmouse  -tag_any_white
+autocmd         +float           +mouse_urxvt     -tcl
-balloon_eval    +folding         +mouse_xterm     +termguicolors
-browse          -footer          +multi_byte      +terminfo
++builtin_terms  +fork()          +multi_lang      +termresponse
+byte_offset     +gettext         -mzscheme        +textobjects
+channel         -hangul_input    +netbeans_intg   +timers
+cindent         +iconv           +num64           +title
-clientserver    +insert_expand   +packages        -toolbar
+clipboard       +job             +path_extra      +user_commands
+cmdline_compl   +jumplist        +perl/dyn        +vertsplit
+cmdline_hist    +keymap          +persistent_undo +virtualedit
+cmdline_info    +lambda          +postscript      +visual
+comments        +langmap         +printer         +visualextra
+conceal         +libcall         +profile         +viminfo
+cryptv          +linebreak       +python/dyn      +vreplace
+cscope          +lispindent      +python3/dyn     +wildignore
+cursorbind      +listcmds        +quickfix        +wildmenu
+cursorshape     +localmap        +reltime         +windows
+dialog_con      -lua             +rightleft       +writebackup
+diff            +menu            +ruby/dyn        -X11
+digraphs        +mksession       +scrollbind      -xfontset
-dnd             +modify_fname    +signs           -xim
-ebcdic          +mouse           +smartindent     -xpm
+emacs_tags      -mouseshape      +startuptime     -xsmp
+eval            +mouse_dec       +statusline      -xterm_clipboard
+ex_extra        -mouse_gpm       -sun_workshop    -xterm_save
+extra_search    -mouse_jsbterm   +syntax
+farsi           +mouse_netterm   +tag_binary
            общесистемный файл vimrc: "/etc/vimrc"
         пользовательский файл vimrc: "$HOME/.vimrc"
  второй пользовательский файл vimrc: "~/.vim/vimrc"
          пользовательский файл exrc: "$HOME/.exrc"
           defaults file: "$VIMRUNTIME/defaults.vim"
          значение $VIM по умолчанию: "/etc"
   значение $VIMRUNTIME по умолчанию: "/usr/share/vim/vim80
"
Параметры компиляции: gcc -c -I. -Iproto -DHAVE_CONFIG_H   -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2
-I/usr/include/ncursesw  -march=x86-64 -mtune=generic -O2 -pipe
-U_FORTIFY_SOURCE -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=1
Сборка: gcc   -L. -pipe -fstack-protector -pipe -Wl,
--as-needed -o vim.exe     -lm    -lncursesw -liconv -lacl -lintl   -Wl,
--enable-auto-import -Wl,--export-all-symbols -Wl,
--enable-auto-image-base -fstack-protector-strong  
-L/usr/lib/perl5/core_perl/CORE -lperl -lpthread -ldl -lcrypt
```

Comment: Я понял что адрес нужно прописывать в двойных кавычках.
" '  ' "
Но почему Vim не работает не пойму

Comment: Смог поставить `Sublime Text` с флагом `-w` но после сохранения и выхода, я получаю ошибку `empty commit message`. Как исправить пока не знаю.

Comment: Избавиться от `empty commit message` я смог когда понял что должен быть хотя бы 1 незакомментированный символ. В итоге Sublime Text работает, а Vim нет. Что не так с Vim не понимаю.

Comment: Попробуйте в файле `.gitconfig` поставить обратный слэш перед пробелом в названии папки `Program Files`.

Comment: И ещё: проверьте, что у вас не запущено других экземпляров vim (если нет в этом уверенности, для надёжности перезагрузите компьютер), и попробуйте проделать то же самое на чистом репозитории.

Comment: @mymedia Компьютер я перезапускал, это не помогало. Перекачал репозиторий и вроде бы помогло. Ошибки, после которых терминал не отвечал прекратились. Думаю теперь нормальна работа восстановлена, спасибо. Просто мне сложно понять что для **Vim** "нормально".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Среди множества ошибок, приведённых вами, я заметил ошибку №325, на которую жаловался Vim. Логически это не совсем ошибка, а лишь сообщение о несохранённых изменениях файла при аварийном завершении предыдущего сеанса работы с редактором. (Судя по всему, вы в первый раз просто убили процесс **vim**, а он не удалил временный файл, нужный для восстановления).

Технически, когда вы вызываете команду `git commit` без указания сообщения фиксации, git создаёт файл `.git/COMMIT_EDITMSG` с шаблоном комментария и открывает редактор для этого файла. В первый раз Vim при открытии создал временный файл `.git/COMMIT_EDITMSG.swp` и не удалил его из-за нештатного завершения. В последующие разы он вам предлагал восстановить исходный файл, но по непонятной причине соответствующее приглашение не выводилось (под виндой часто бывают всякие глюки). Впрочем, если удалить тот файл `.swp`, я полагаю, редактор заработает.

Отключить функциональность подобных временных файлом можно, отключив настройку **swapfile**. Добавьте следующую строчку в ваш конфигурационный файл Vim.

```
set noswapfile
```

Подробнее об изначальной ошибке можно почитать в справке, вызвав её командой `:help E325` из Vim. <sup>[веб-версия](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/usr_11.html#E325)</sup>

Обратите внимание, Git проверяет статус выхода вызванного редактора, так что если при редактировании произойдёт ошибка, фиксация отменяется. Кроме того, без указания параметра `--allow-empty-message` Git откажется что-либо фиксировать, если в файле `COMMIT_EDITMSG` не будет ни одной строчки, не начинающейся с решётки `#`.

Comment: Спасибо, я эту информацию весь день искал. Очевидно, удалив репозиторий с компьютера я удалил и `.swp` файл. Загрузив репозиторий заново, этого файла там конечно же не было, и ошибка пропала. Ещё раз спасибо.